# SELECT * FROM people WHERE user_id='$user_id' ORDER BY time GROUP BY surname

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to pull out all the entries in my database that relate to a certain user_id, order them by the time they were entered into the database (this is php unix time() seconds) and then group them by surname so that they sit with entries of the same surname.

This is the query so far.. Although it only gives me a certain amount of entries.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE user_token='$user_token'
        ORDER BY time GROUP BY surname";
```

What is the correct way to use ORDER and GROUP by in order to get all of the results out grouped by the surname but ordered by the time the were entered? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly means doesn't work? And what is expected output if there are 2 people with the same surname, joined at different time?

Comment: try to look what is the error using mysql_error()

Comment: -1 for not even stating what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause should be the last, but you have to specify fields to be aggregated.

Such as:

```
SELECT surname, count(*) 
    FROM people 
    WHERE user_token='$user_token'
    GROUP BY surname
    ORDER BY surname
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, although it dosen't seem to retrieve all entries.. I just get one of each surname. I assume that the `count(*)` is supposed to count all the surnames? so then you can group them all and order them all..?

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your SQL, syntax, SQL-injection vulnerability and probably you are using obsolete database extension. So, here is what it should really look like:

```
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host";
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
$sql = "SELECT surname, count(id) FROM people WHERE user_token=:usr_token ORDER BY time GROUP BY surname";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt->execute(array(':usr_token'=>$user_token))){
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
else{
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    die("Error executing query");
}
```

Refer to [PDO manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) for details